# How to I modify the internal margins (padding) of a UWP numberbox?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to align some controls in a UWP GUI. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to adjust the gaps between the numbers inside a [UWP numberbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/number-box)
i.e. these ones:

[image: padding illustration]

Is there any way to adjust them? I've tried adjusting the template using setters with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the `TextBox` whose name is `InputBox` in the default style of `NumberBox` control and set the `Padding` property to adjust the gaps between the numbers inside the `NumberBox` controls.

Please check the following steps:

1. Open the **Document Outline** pane, find you `NumberBox` control and right-click it. Choose the option **Edit Template > Edit a Copy**. Then a default style of the `NumberBox` control will be applied to your `NumberBox` control.
2. Find the `TextBox` control named `InputBox`.
3. Try to **Debug** your project. If there is a `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` error, then delete the `InputScope` property and `TextAlignment` property in `InputBox`. Rebuild your project, it will run well.
4. Add a `Padding` property to the `InputBox` control to adjust the gaps such as `Padding="0,2,0,0"`.
5. Build your project.